# Is there some way I can add Image to context menu of Notification Icon?

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I've a WPF application, in which I use a notification icon with the use Forms. I need to have a context menu for this notification icon, where each menu item got to have image property as well along with the header.

Comment: What do you need help with? Do you have a menu yet?

Comment: As of now what I've done is, I made a WPF form with Window Style property disabled and having start location near the taskbar. This form has normal wpf menu items, which support image along with header.

Comment: what I need is to do the same with context menu.

Comment: Yes. A menu should do be doing the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's a WinForms component rather than a WPF component but you can still use [`NotifyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) in WPF. Set the `ContextMenu` or `ContextMenuStrip` properties to assign a menu to the icon.

**EDIT**: Judging by your comments and answer I believe that you are trying to use `MenuItem` which does not have built-in support for displaying images. However, that deficiency was long ago removed with the introduction of [`ToolStripMenuItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.aspx). This has an `Image` property, or alternatively the `ImageIndex` property is you prefer to use image lists.

Comment: yes, you can add context menu to NotifyIcon in winforms. But in Wpf menu has an icon attribute with which you can set an image in the menuitem, which is not there in winforms.

Comment: Do you mean that this answers the question? Or did you find something else?

Comment: i've added the link as an answer.

Comment: And I've updated my answer to help further. You don't need owner draw at all!

Comment: Oh... Great!! that saves me a lot of time!!

Comment: could you help me with one more thing? I did the app using contextmenustrip as you said. In my app, when I click on the Item1, i want a new item, Item2 to be added, one in its place(replacing it). In the Item1's click event I wrote code to remove it and wrote the code to add Item2 to that index; the replacement happens but on clicking, the menu goes hiding. Is there someway I could keep the context menu open upon clicking the item.

Comment: That's not how menus work. You would have to write your own menu code in full. Even then I'm not sure how practical that is.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could find what I wanted. You need to enable OwnerDraw property of the Forms Menu and write two events part of it. Here is the link to the url:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/cs_menus.aspx

Comment: Any reason why you didn't just use the `Image` property like I said? It seems odd to go to all these lengths when the feature you want is trivially already built in. Are you making the mistake of using `MenuItem` rather than [`ToolStripMenuItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.aspx)?

Comment: yes... i was not aware of ToolStripMenuItem , what I used was MenuItem

Comment: OK then, that solves it. It is simply trivial to do what you need with NotifyIcon and ToolStripMenuItem as per my answer. Glad I wasn't going mad after all!!